App doesn't adhere to program policies Your (Android) app isn’t ready to show ads yet
I have applied for google admob multiple times but I always get the same message:

We completed our app review. Unfortunately, some issues need
to be fixed before your app is ready to show ads. The app doesn't adhere
to program policies

But on the issue tab, there are no issues. The same app in iOS is approved although the app is written in flutter.

The app is ID is com.bazarsoftech.fasobiz

While this question would be considered on-topic, I doubt anyone on StackOverflow can give you a concrete answer - Google is not always very transparent with their app reviews and you're likely going to have to contact their support to learn more (good luck)

@Marsroverr I disagree it's on topic.  It's not a programming question, it's a legal question about terms of service of AdMob.  It may become a programming question if they could provide enough data to show there's a programming problem, but its nowhere near there yet.

@GabeSechan I'd say questions about deploying software could also be considered about software development, but I see where you're coming from. On-topic or not though they're not going to get a good answer if they're about Google products lol
